# Is there a free web site hosting like google sites

Tags: web, project-hosting

Is there a free website hosting, sort of like google sites, but where I can upload my own html files and css?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[github pages](https://pages.github.com) is great for static websites. If you want to run a dynamic website then you could try pythonanywhere or amazon aws, if you are willing to spend a little bit of money.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively if you want to set up your own server using either Node/Ruby/Java/PHP/Python/Go, you may try [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/free). It does come with a [free plan](https://www.heroku.com/pricing).

Answer (score 0):

I agree GitHub can host static webpages but for dynamic sites implementing JS, Ruby on Rails there are other paid web hosting domains.